# swipe between 3 state's of a component using React js swiper

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

After trying to use swiper library on React js to slide up/down a component i can't get it.

All of example are to change between differente "slides", nothing about a position os same component.

Here is a example of what i mean:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7z9R.png)

any solution or example to do it

example as i want but without 3 different slides:

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-robinson-6xx1f5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-robinson-6xx1f5?file=/src/App.js